# nested where condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, nested, where-clause

from this data how can i fetch all users where user_id in tbl_attendance not having current date with application_status 3 and 4

```
attendance_id   user_id      date_in        attendance_status status 0=absent 1=present 3 = onleave 4 = onoff
    1            1          2017-02-05      1
    2            36         2017-02-11      4
    3            36         2017-02-11      4
    4            36         2017-02-11      3
    5            1          2017-02-02      1
    6            36         2017-02-01      1
```

my code is like this

```
$date=date('Y-m-d');
$this->db->where('tbl_users.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM tbl_attendance WHERE tbl_attendance.date_in= "'.$date.'" )');

$this->db->where_in( 'tbl_attendance.attendance_status', array( '3', '4' ) );
```

want to combine those two lines and produce the output like if current date is present in 3 or 4 please help me

Comment: MOVE YOUR SECOND WHERE CONDITION INTO INSIDE THE SUB QUERY LIKE THIS $this->db->where('tbl_users.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM tbl_attendance WHERE tbl_attendance.date_in != "'.$date.'" AND tbl_attendance.attendance_status IN (3,4) ) );

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.To combine two conditions

```
$this->db->where("tbl_users.user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM tbl_attendance WHERE tbl_attendance.date_in='$date' AND tbl_attendance.attendance_status IN(3,4))");
```

Answer (score 0):

seeing you're using query builder...

```
$this->db->group_start()
    $this->db->where_in( 'tbl_attendance.attendance_status', array( '3', '4' ) );
    $this->db->where_not_in('tbl_users.user_id', 'SELECT user_id FROM tbl_attendance WHERE tbl_attendance.date_in = '. $date, false)
$this->db->group_end()
```

should work